# Algorithm to position samples minimizing error

Tags: algorithms, optimization, numerical-algorithms

We have a 1D function `f(x)`. We would like to approximate this function with a polyline of `n` points. How can we find the `x` position for these points so the polyline approximates `f(x)` with low error (not necessarily optimal but if it was, then even better)?

What algorithms are available to solve this problem? What are their trade-offs?

Example: the following two polylines have the same number of points but the second one approximates better the curve.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm.

Comment: How do you measure error?  Mean squared error?

Comment: Are the points restricted to be on the curve (as in your example) or can we use endpoints that are off the line if this reduces the overall error?

Comment: @Jakube Thanks that's a good one!

Comment: @D.W For both questions: any way would work. I don't really have any restrictions in those redards